# C error: ld: library not found for -lgcc Collect2: error

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile the basic "Hello World" C code with gcc but the following error appears:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code itself it's fine, ran it in another computer without any problems.

Here there's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSlNV.png) of how the terminal looks like. I am not sure if I missed something when downloading gcc or something.

I am on Yosemite if it's of any importance and have the 5.1.0 version of gcc.

Comment: If you post the code it'll be easier to help you

Comment: The code it's fine, checked it in another computer and compiled right. It's the basic "Hello World" program. http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html

Comment: There's definitely a problem with your gcc installation.  I was going to suggest you ask this on http://apple.stackexchang.com but there is an almost identical question there without an answer.

Comment: If there was something wrong with the installation of gcc wouldnt it return me an error when checking for its version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an incompatibility of the compiler with Yosemite I think. Have to compile with gcc4.9 and it works just fine.

You compile with gcc4.9 this way

```
gcc-4.9 -o output file.c
```